# iCloud documents greyed out for guest user

Tags: macos, icloud, nsdocument

NSDocuments saved by administrator account on iCloud are greyed out when accessed by Guest Account.
How does one ensure that NSDocuments saved can be accessed by all users?

Answer (score 0):

> How does one ensure that NSDocuments saved can be accessed by all users

One does not.

Documents synced via iCloud are available only to Mac OS X user accounts that have access to the iCloud account. Other accounts on the Mac do not get access unless they're using the same iCloud account. There's no support in iCloud for making documents available outside of the account-- that's not how it was designed. If you want to make those documents available, you'd have to copy them to a shared location by hand.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have just found that by setting Keychain Groups to ON will solve the problem. I hope apple agrees.